How to query based on related tables and grouping the records as per the nearest range values?
I have 2 tables containing roll no and policy numbers in a relation like, 1 roll no can have multiple policies and multiple transactions based on a single roll number.
table A



id
policy
rollno
tax




1
P1
R1
60


2
P2
R1
30


3
P3
R2
120


4
P4
R2
35



table B



id
amnt
rollno




1
30
R1


2
140
R1


3
90
R2


4
65
R2


5
20
R2


6
200
R2


7
130
R2


8
85
R2



For table B, rollno R2 has 6 transactions. Now the logic will be like, I need a query that will group the transactions based on the nearest tax calculations from the table A with policy number. SO, the result will be like below: For ex: if "amnt" 90 is closer to "tax" 120 and 20 is closer to 35, the results will be grouped accordingly.
table C



id
amnt
rollno
policy
tax




1
30
R1
P2
30


2
140
R1
P1
60


3
90
R2
P3
120


4
65
R2
P3
120


5
20
R2
P4
35


6
200
R2
P3
120


7
130
R2
P3
120


8
85
R2
P3
120



So far I tried like the below query but it is listing double records when I am trying to query the results. I tried the below query but it is not working. I am not so expert in SQL.
select b.*, a.policy, (select max(a.tax) from tableA a where b.amnt>a.tax) y
from tableB join tableA c on b.rollno=a.rollno
union
select b.*, a.policy, (select min(a.tax) from tableA a where b.amnt<a.tax) y
from tableB join tableA c on b.rollno=a.rollno


Show us what you've tried.

I have edited the question and tried the query, as I am not expert in SQL

What to do if the difference is the same for multiple taxes?

Yes it can be same

Your query worked like a charm sir

Yes, the difference can be same for multiple taxes sir. But the requirement is itself not clear from the project itself. Whatever they asked for, I asked sir in this platform. I will ask my manager regarding this  query and will comment here only.

Note questions should be absolutely clear. If other people have similar issues and are looking for a solution, they might get to this question and use the query proposed in the answer. Then they might get an incorrect result because you refused to clarify what to do in edge cases. Do you really think all those people should run in trouble or don't you think it would be better that you improve your question? It's very unpleasant you are obviously not going to explain what to do in case of identic differences.

Yes you are right sir. I am sorry absolutely but whatever I was asked I posted the question here.

The closest means the minimum of the absolute value of the difference:
select id, amnt, rollno, policy, tax 
from (
    select d.*,
        min(dist) over(partition by rollno, amnt) as min_dist
    from (
        select b.id, b.amnt, rollno, a.policy, a.tax,
            abs(a.tax - b.amnt) as dist
        from table_a a
        join table_b b using( rollno )
    ) d
)
where dist = min_dist
order by id, rollno
;


Thanks sir, this is exactly working fine

Note this will "multiply" rows if the difference is the same for different taxes! OP is refusing to tell us what they want in this case. But should be mentioned if other people have similar problems. See https://dbfiddle.uk/ECBlknY4
